# 'vsync' is deprecated and shouldn't be used

Tags: flutter

After updating to flutter version `3.0.3` I'm getting this warning while trying to use `AnimatedSize` widget:

```
'vsync' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. This field is now ignored. This feature was deprecated after v2.2.0-10.1.pre..
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.
```

```dart
child: AnimatedSize(
   vsync: this,
   curve: Curves.easeIn,
   duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
   child: Text("test"),
),
```

so what is the replacement?

Comment: Can you provide more snippet and your flutter version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double _size = 50.0;
  bool _large = false;

  void _updateSize() {
    setState(() {
      _size = _large ? 250.0 : 100.0;
      _large = !_large;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _updateSize(),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.amberAccent,
        child: AnimatedSize(
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
          child: FlutterLogo(size: _size),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

More information [AnimatedSize](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSize-class.html)

Comment: yeah I was also wondering, just wanted to help the thread creator and show the actual use of it from the docs where vsync isn't needed anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the field, doesn't need it anymore,

the updated docs example also removed it [AnimatedSize class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSize-class.html)